# Failed to create view. Invalid field name

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to save a view.
several of my fields are of type timestamp.
i get the following error message:

Failed to create view. Invalid field name "Myfield.usec". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Field name is valid for running the query from the browser, and its name is "Myfield" (the ".usec" appears only in the error message and probably represents its type).

When converting it to Integer, I get no error.
Is this a known bug? something I did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write as:

`select FORMAT_UTC_USEC(timestamp) as timestamp ...`

Also you need to de-reference nested record type fields for views:

`SELECT utm.campaign as utm_campaign ...`

Comment: This works... can anyone explain why timestamp needs data type conversion while other data types works straightforward?

Comment: The two issues that @Pentium10 mentions are actually related. Timestamps are stored internally as nested types, and views currently don't allow nested results. We're working on a fix, but unfortunately, it isn't straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there are no record or timestamp fields we cannot use `SELECT table.*` for a view query. We run a query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.title AS cat_title
FROM [dataset1.table] AS a,
LEFT JOIN EACH [dataset2.table] AS b
ON a.cat_id = b.id
```

And get an error:
    *Failed to create view. Invalid field name "a.id". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.*

So we have to specify each field from a table:

```
SELECT a.id as id, a.title as title, a.lang as lang, b.title AS author
FROM [dataset1.table] AS a,
LEFT JOIN EACH [dataset2.table] AS b
ON a.cat_id = b.id
```

This is very uncomfortable, and would be really nice to fix.